# How do you structure unit tests for multiple objects that exhibit the same behavior?

Tags: unit-testing

In a lot of cases I might have an existing class with some behavior:

```
class Lion
{
    public void Eat(Herbivore herbivore) { ... }
}
```

...and I have a unit test...

```
[TestMethod]
public void Lion_can_eat_herbivore()
{
    var herbivore = buildHerbivoreForEating();
    var test = BuildLionForTest();
    test.Eat(herbivore);
    Assert.IsEaten(herbivore);
}
```

Now, what happens is I need to create a Tiger class with idential behavior to that of the Lion:

```
class Tiger
{
    public void Eat(Herbivore herbivore) { ... }
}
```

...and since I want the same behavior, I need to run the same test, I do something like this:

```
interface IHerbivoreEater
{
    void Eat(Herbivore herbivore);
}
```

...and I refactor my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Lion_can_eat_herbivore()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_can_eat_herbivore(BuildLionForTest);
}


public void IHerbivoreEater_can_eat_herbivore(Func<IHerbivoreEater> builder)
{
    var herbivore = buildHerbivoreForEating();
    var test = builder();
    test.Eat(herbivore);
    Assert.IsEaten(herbivore);
}
```

...and then I add another test for my new `Tiger` class:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Tiger_can_eat_herbivore()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_can_eat_herbivore(BuildTigerForTest);
}
```

...and then I refactor my `Lion` and `Tiger` classes (usually by inheritance, but sometimes by composition):

```
class Lion : HerbivoreEater { }
class Tiger : HerbivoreEater { }

abstract class HerbivoreEater : IHerbivoreEater
{
    public void Eat(Herbivore herbivore) { ... }
}
```

...and all is well.  However, since the functionality is now in the `HerbivoreEater` class, it now feels like there's something wrong with having tests for each of these behaviors on each subclass.  Yet it's the subclasses that are actually being consumed, and it's only an implementation detail that they happen to share overlapping behaviors (`Lions` and `Tigers` may have totally different end-uses, for instance).

It seems redundant to test the same code multiple times, but there are cases where the subclass can and does override the functionality of the base class (yes, it might violate the LSP, but lets face it, `IHerbivoreEater` is just a convenient testing interface - it may not matter to the end-user).  So these tests do have some value, I think.

What do other people do in this situation?  Do you just move your test to the base class, or do you test all subclasses for the expected behavior?

**EDIT**:

Based on the answer from @pdr I think we should consider this: the `IHerbivoreEater` is just a method signature contract; it does not specify behavior.  For instance:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Tiger_eats_herbivore_haunches_first()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_eats_herbivore_haunches_first(BuildTigerForTest);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Cheetah_eats_herbivore_haunches_first()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_eats_herbivore_haunches_first(BuildCheetahForTest);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Lion_eats_herbivore_head_first()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_eats_herbivore_head_first(BuildLionForTest);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of argument, shouldn't you have an `Animal` class which contains `Eat`? All animals eat, and therefore the `Tiger` and `Lion` class could inherit from animal.

Comment: @Nick - that is a good point, but I think that's a different situation.  As @pdr pointed out, if you put the `Eat` behavior in the base class, then all subclasses should exhibit the same `Eat` behavior.  However, I'm talking about 2 relatively unrelated classes that happen to share a behavior.  Consider, for example, the `Fly` behavior of `Brick` and `Person` which, we may assume, exhibit a similar flying behavior, but it doesn't necessarily make sense to have them derive from a common base class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is great because it shows how tests truly drive the way you think about design. You are sensing problems in the design and asking the right questions.

There are two ways of looking at this.

IHerbivoreEater is a contract. All IHerbivoreEaters must have an Eat method which accepts a Herbivore. Now, your tests do not care how it is eaten; your Lion might start with the haunches and Tiger might start at the throat. All your test cares about is that after it calls Eat, the Herbivore is eaten.

On the other hand, part of what you're saying is that all IHerbivoreEaters eat the Herbivore in exactly the same way (hence the base class). That being the case, there is no point in having an IHerbivoreEater contract at all. It offers nothing. You may as well just inherit from HerbivoreEater.

Or maybe do away with Lion and Tiger completely.

But, if Lion and Tiger are different in every sense apart from their eating habits, then you need to start wondering if you are going to run into problems with a complex inheritance tree. What if you also want to derive both classes from Feline, or only Lion class from KingOfItsDomain (along with Shark, perhaps). This is where LSP truly comes in.

I would suggest that common code is better encapsulated.

```
public class Lion : IHerbivoreEater
{
    private IHerbivoreEatingStrategy _herbivoreEatingStrategy;
    private Lion (IHerbivoreEatingStrategy herbivoreEatingStrategy)
    {
        _herbivoreEatingStrategy = herbivoreEatingStrategy;
    }

    public Lion() : this(new StandardHerbivoreEatingStrategy())
    {
    }

    public void Eat(Herbivore herbivore)
    {
        _herbivoreEatingStrategy.Eat(herbivore);
    }
}
```

Same goes for Tiger.

Now, here's a beautiful thing developing (beautiful because I didn't intend it). If you just make that private constructor available to the test, you can pass in a fake IHerbivoreEatingStrategy and simply test that the message is passed on to the encapsulated object properly.

And your complex test, the one you were worrying about in the first place, only has to test the StandardHerbivoreEatingStrategy. One class, one set of tests, no duplicated code to worry about.

And if, later, you want to tell Tigers that they should eat their herbivores a different way, none of these tests have to change. You're simply creating a new HerbivoreEatingStrategy and testing that. The wiring is tested at integration-test level.

Comment: +1 The Strategy Pattern was the first thing that came into my head reading the question.

Comment: Very good, but now replace "unit test" in my question with "integration test".  Don't we end up with the same problem? `IHerbivoreEater` is a contract, but only in so much as I need it for testing.  It seems to me that this is one case where duck typing would really help.  I just want to send them both to the same test logic now.  I don't think the interface should make a promise of the behavior.  The tests should do that.

Comment: great question, great answer. You don't have to have a private constructor; you can wire IHerbivoreEatingStrategy to StandardHerbivoreEatingStrategy using an IoC container.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: "I don't think the interface should make a promise of the behavior. The tests should do that." That's exactly what I'm saying. If it does make a promise of the behaviour, you should get rid of it and just use the (base-)class. You don't need it for testing at all.

Comment: @azheglov: Agree, but my answer was long enough already :)

Comment: @pdr - in the case of using a common base class rather than an interface, would you still run the tests against all the subclasses, just as I've shown?

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: As I said, the base class option would be  a last resort. If there is no difference in my program between Tiger and Lion, why have those classes at all? If there is a difference, I worry about LSP. That said, I never say never and if I did go down that road, I suspect I would only test the logic code once. Depending on various details, I might even consider a subclass just for testing.

Comment: @pdr: agreed...

Comment: @pdr - on a related note, then, how do your integration tests prove that the correct strategy was wired up?

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: There comes a point where you should ask a new question rather than discussing here. There also comes a point, in any OO discussion, where real-object analogies break down. We're at both here. Unlike Lions and Tigers, who do things for their own reasons, your classes' implementations will be different for software reasons. Also, this is where IOC containers come into their own.

Comment: @pdr - condescend much?

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: Not my intention. Sorry if it came off that way. It's just that answering your latest question isn't that easy in 600 characters and it's completely off-topic from the original question, so I don't want to edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems redundant to test the same code multiple times, but there are cases where the subclass can and does override the functionality of the base class

In a round-about way you're asking whether its appropriate to use white-box knowledge to omit some tests. From a black-box perspective, `Lion` and `Tiger` are different classes. So someone without familiarity with the code would test them, but you with deep implementation knowledge know that you can get away with simply testing one animal.

Part of the reason for developing unit tests is to allow yourself to refactor later but **maintain the same black-box interface**. The unit tests are helping you ensure your classes continue to meet their contract with clients, or at the very least forces you to realize and think carefully how the contract might change. You yourself realize that `Lion` or `Tiger` might override `Eat` at some later point. If this is remotely possible, a simple unit test testing that each animal you support can eat, in the manner of:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Tiger_can_eat_herbivore()
{
    IHerbivoreEater_can_eat_herbivore(BuildTigerForTest);
}
```

should be very simple to do and suffice and will ensure that you can detect when objects fail to meet their contract.

Comment: I wonder if this question really just boils down to a preference of black-box vs. white-box testing.  I lean towards the black-box camp, which is perhaps why I'm testing the way I am.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right. Think of a unit test as the test of the behavior of a single usage of your new code. This is the same call you would make from production code.

In that situation, you're completely correct; a user of a Lion or Tiger will not (won't have to, at least) care that they're both HerbivoreEaters and that the code that actually runs for the method is common to both up in the base class. Similarly, a user of a HerbivoreEater abstract (provided by the concrete Lion or Tiger) won't care which it has. What they care about is that their Lion, Tiger, or unknown concrete implementation of HerbivoreEater will Eat() a Herbivore correctly.

So, what you're basically testing is that a Lion will Eat as intended, and that a Tiger will Eat as intended. It's important to test both, because it may not always be true that they both eat exactly the same way; by testing both, you ensure that the one you didn't want to change, didn't. Because those are both of the HerbivoreEaters defined, at least until you add Cheetah you have also tested that all HerbivoreEaters will Eat as intended. Your testing both completely covers and adequately exercises the code (provided that you also make all expected assertions of what should result from a HerbivoreEater eating a Herbivore).